# collapsing my data down extracting diagonal elements

Tags: r

The way I have extracted my results somehow kept them as diagonal elements in a data frame. I would like to reduce the data down, keeping the row names and col names. I.e. merge the row names and col names.

```
               1750:10-K:2006 1800:10-K:2006 1923:10-K:2006 2488:10-K:2006
1750:10-K:2005      0.9291217             NA             NA             NA
1800:10-K:2005             NA      0.9690067             NA             NA
1923:10-K:2005             NA             NA      0.8584429             NA
2488:10-K:2005             NA             NA             NA       0.956372
2969:10-K:2005             NA             NA             NA             NA
3133:10-K:2005             NA             NA             NA             NA
3197:10-K:2005             NA             NA             NA             NA
3333:10-K:2005             NA             NA             NA             NA
3370:10-K:2005             NA             NA             NA             NA
3673:10-K:2005             NA             NA             NA             NA
               2969:10-K:2006 3133:10-K:2006 3197:10-K:2006 3333:10-K:2006
1750:10-K:2005             NA             NA             NA             NA
1800:10-K:2005             NA             NA             NA             NA
1923:10-K:2005             NA             NA             NA             NA
2488:10-K:2005             NA             NA             NA             NA
2969:10-K:2005       0.861327             NA             NA             NA
3133:10-K:2005             NA      0.9375159             NA             NA
3197:10-K:2005             NA             NA      0.9633629             NA
3333:10-K:2005             NA             NA             NA      0.9752259
3370:10-K:2005             NA             NA             NA             NA
3673:10-K:2005             NA             NA             NA             NA
               3370:10-K:2006 3673:10-K:2006
1750:10-K:2005             NA             NA
1800:10-K:2005             NA             NA
1923:10-K:2005             NA             NA
2488:10-K:2005             NA             NA
2969:10-K:2005             NA             NA
3133:10-K:2005             NA             NA
3197:10-K:2005             NA             NA
3333:10-K:2005             NA             NA
3370:10-K:2005       0.941602             NA
3673:10-K:2005             NA      0.9745789
```

Expected output:

```
1750:10-K:2005_1750:10-K:2006     0.9291217 
1800:10-K:2005_1800:10-K:2006     0.9690067
1923:10-K:2005_1923:10-K:2006     0.8584429
2488:10-K:2005_2488:10-K:2006     0.956372
```

Data:

```
structure(list(`1750:10-K:2006` = c(0.929121725727165, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `1800:10-K:2006` = c(NA, 0.96900670959669, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `1923:10-K:2006` = c(NA, NA, 
0.858442889654398, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `2488:10-K:2006` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, 0.956371967288172, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `2969:10-K:2006` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.861326963904054, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `3133:10-K:2006` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.93751593784196, NA, NA, NA, NA), `3197:10-K:2006` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.963362873672737, NA, NA, NA), `3333:10-K:2006` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.975225879729218, NA, NA), `3370:10-K:2006` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.941602039119482, NA), `3673:10-K:2006` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.974578948898938)), row.names = c("1750:10-K:2005", 
"1800:10-K:2005", "1923:10-K:2005", "2488:10-K:2005", "2969:10-K:2005", 
"3133:10-K:2005", "3197:10-K:2005", "3333:10-K:2005", "3370:10-K:2005", 
"3673:10-K:2005"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: `reshape2::melt(as.matrix(dat), na.rm=TRUE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `diag` but you have to convert to matrix first, i.e.

```
data.frame(v1 = rownames(df), v2 = diag(as.matrix(df)))

#               v1        v2
#1  1750:10-K:2005 0.9291217
#2  1800:10-K:2005 0.9690067
#3  1923:10-K:2005 0.8584429
#4  2488:10-K:2005 0.9563720
#5  2969:10-K:2005 0.8613270
#6  3133:10-K:2005 0.9375159
#7  3197:10-K:2005 0.9633629
#8  3333:10-K:2005 0.9752259
#9  3370:10-K:2005 0.9416020
#10 3673:10-K:2005 0.9745789
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with dplyr:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  gather(KPI,Value,-rowname) %>%
  mutate(KPI = paste0(rowname,KPI,sep="_")) %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  select(-rowname)
```